# Wordpress, Woocommerce custom REST endpoint doesn't work if called from within a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, rest

I am trying to get the result of a custom REST endpoint inside the plugin internally.
The REST point looks like this:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function(){
   register_rest_route( 'my-route/', '(?P<id>\d+), array(
      'method'    => 'GET',
      'callback'  => 'get_custom_price_for_product',
   ));
});
```

It works when tested in RESTClient and it also works when I use `wp_remote_get` or `wp_remote_request`. The callback function does only some elementary stuff. It takes the `ID` from the route, gets the product with `wc_get_product()` and returns its price. That's why I am not including the callback here.

The problem is that `wp_remote_get` and `wp_remote_request` are both pretty slow when used from withing the site itself so they are not suitable for batch processing of many products.

The reason why I need this is another plugin that changes prices on the fly (it is called XL Plugins Finale) and there is no way to get those front-end only prices without creating a REST point. At least that's what I got from the plugin developers as a suggestion.

I tried to use `new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', $route )` with `rest_do_request` like this:

```
$request = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', 'https://example.com/wp-json/my-route/15063' );
$response = rest_do_request( $request );
```

but this always returns `rest_no_route` like it doesn't exist.

I also tried to define the method in the rest route as `WP_REST_Server::READABLE` without any change.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: On what hook are you trying to fetch the data from the rest endpoint? If you're hooking to any hook before `rest_api_init` it'll probably fail, since REST endpoints are not initialized yet.

That'd be my guess.

Comment: Well, for now I am just testing it inside Wordpress admin. I created a testing admin page where I check the output. So I guess the hook I am using is `admin_menu` because that is where the `add_menu_page` is hooked containing the callback for my testing page. Is that too soon?

Comment: No, I think it should work. But I did notice you used the entire URL, since you're creating the rest endpoint did you try: ```$request = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/my-route/15063' );
$response = rest_do_request( $request );
``` without the full URL?

Comment: Yes I did. The behavior doesn't change at all.